# Basic actionscript statement

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I've never done any ActionScript before, but what does the line marked below do?

```
var s:Object = {};

for (var i:int = 0; i < 1000; i++)
{
    s[i] ? s[i]++ : s[i] = -1; //this line
}
```

It looks similar to a C# shorthand `If...Else` but I don't understand what the condition is in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operator) aka [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_operator).

```
if(s[i]){
    s[i]++
}else{
    s[i] = -1;
}
```

Comment: So, in this case, would an equivalent check be `if(s[i] != null)` since `s[]` doesn't contain bool values?

Comment: Yes. You can check not only boolean values. And adviсe: if keys of your hash is integers use array instead of hash.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into using arrays as they are integers.